# How can accept both JSON and XML?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, postman

I saw [similar question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC72l.jpg), and added to consumes parameters both MediaType. But it can't help me :(

I want to accept requests in json and xml formats.
There is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/client", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String createClient(@Valid @RequestBody ClientDto clientDto) {
        return clientService.createUser(clientDto);
    }
}
```

Dto class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class ClientDto {
    private long client_id;
    @NotNull
    private String first_name;
    @NotNull
    private String last_name;
    private List<AccountDto> accounts;

getter//setters//constructor//
}
```

I sending requests from Postman. I haven't problems with json.
But I can't accept xml format.

```
2021-08-15 20:08:43.600  WARN 15820 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Regarding, *"I saw similar question, but it can't help me"* -- *what* similar question did you see (link please) and how did it not help you? These details may help allow us to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by @XmlRootElement annotation

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ClientDto {
    private long client_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private List<AccountDto> accounts;
...
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AccountDto {
    ...
}
```